Convert Umi uint8Array signature to base64
When sending an umi transaction using sendAndConfirm method, a response object that contains a uint8Array signature and RPC response is returned.
How do we convert the uint8Array signature to base64

You can deserialize the result using the built in umi deserializer
import { base58 } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi/serializers";

async function createBubblegumTree() {
    const merkleTree = generateSigner(umi);

    const uintSig = await (
        await (
            await createTree(umi, {
                merkleTree,
                maxDepth: 14,
                maxBufferSize: 64,
            })
        ).sendAndConfirm(umi)
    ).signature;

    const b64Sig = base58.deserialize(uintSig)[0];
    console.log(b64Sig);
}

createBubblegumTree().then().catch(console.error);

